# Question concerning: $P(n)=\left\lfloor \sqrt{n!+{n^2(n+1)\over 2}}\right\rfloor, n\ge2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, prime-numbers

Let $$P(n)=\left\lfloor \sqrt{n!+{n^2(n+1)\over 2}}\right\rfloor, n\ge2$$

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.

Where $P_k$ and $P_j$ are two highest prime numbers such that,

$$P_j \le P(n^2-1)$$

$$P_k \le P(n^2)$$

Then we have $$P_k-nP_j=c$$
 The value of $c$ is very small even the values of $P_j$ and $P_k$ are very large.

**For examples:**

$P(3)$ then $3\le 4$

$P(4)$ then $7\le 8$

$$7-2\times3=1\tag1$$

$P(8)$ then $199\le 201 $

$P(9)$ then $601\le 602 $

$$601-3\times 199=4\tag2$$

$P(15)$ then $1143529\le 1143535$

$P(16)$ then $4574123\le 4574143$

$$4574123-4\times1143529=7\tag3$$

> Can $c$ be represent in term of a function of $n$, $$c=f(n)?$$

If not exact... can it $c\approx f(n)?$

Comment: Is $P_k\le P(n^2)$ a typo (because the prime corresponding to $P(15)$ you calculated is the largest prime below $P(15)$ ) ?

Comment: Think I got it now. Are the first $15$ numbers $$[0, 1, 4, 7, 2, 361, 90, 715, 1228, 867, 7320, -149, 1800, 12627, 1456]$$ ?

Comment: It should be possible to calculate a reasonable approximation based on the prime number theorem, but an exact formula will be impossible.

Comment: very interesting thank you @Peter. How did you calculate it so quick?

Comment: I used  PARI/GP , a computational software for large numbers. Interesting that there is (at least) one negative value in the sequence.

Comment: Hi @Peter can you list more of the values. Thank you.

Comment: I post an answer, but please check the values to see whether my program actually does what is intented.

Comment: ok thank you so much @peter

Answer (score 1):

According to PARI/GP, the first $25$ values are :

```
? p
%40 = (n)->sqrtint(n!+n^2*(n+1)/2)
? s
%41 = (m)->precprime(p(m))
? vector(25,q,s(q^2)-q*s(q^2-1))
%42 = [0, 1, 4, 7, 2, 361, 90, 715, 1228, 867, 7320, -149, 1800, 12627, 1456, 35
17, 9090, 6389, 18186, 23113, 9550, 74739, 27120, 19301, 132154]
?
```

$p$ and $s$ are the necessary self-defined functions.

Some more values :

```
? q=26;print(q,"  ",s(q^2)-q*s(q^2-1))
26  58797
? q=27;print(q,"  ",s(q^2)-q*s(q^2-1))
27  56476
? q=28;print(q,"  ",s(q^2)-q*s(q^2-1))
28  36835
? q=29;print(q,"  ",s(q^2)-q*s(q^2-1))
29  145260
? q=30;print(q,"  ",s(q^2)-q*s(q^2-1))
30  15049
```

Comment: I don't think zero is in the sequence.

Comment: You are right, I started with $n=1$

Comment: Note that there is a probability (extremely small) that the precprime-command gives a number that is not actually prime.